openmv failed to detect the image sensor or image sensor is detached
when I use the openmv. the ide tell me: RuntimeError: Failed to detect the image sensor or image sensor is detached.
how can I fix it.i try to plug the usb again but fail
my computer is Mac and I do not know where I can installing drivers.
